# how to make a button blink in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a button in iOS that I want to blink. Specifically, it should go from the highlighted to normal state several times a second. What is the best way to implement this? Perhaps using a timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think any sort of blinking button would be an iOS style violation.

Comment: To avoid any problems you may want to blink it once or twice or with long gaps in between (so that its more subtle and not very against apples HIG)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to induce seizures, I see.

Yes, you could use a timer. Check out `NSTimer`'s `+(NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`. The method it calls by selector could simply alternate the button's state.

One alternative may be to use animations.